# What's this encode type?

Tags: encoding, character-encoding, decode, encode

> 3f5b2e3acfd36066b8cb4114e706d79d270c7c4219a6312c4b40f995f138c2ba5ba2b62aa4831e0bdac8f8802626d3c4f8872b8996d8bebc5ab697e0c702a6eb

what kind of encoding is this.

I've searched on google, still can't find it.

Please help me

Comment: hexadecimal encoding, every pair of hex characters represents the value of a byte. 128 characters -> 64 bytes.

Comment: Please take the 2-minute [tour]. Moreover, open [Help] and read at least [ask]. Then, [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Comment *hexadecimal encoding, every pair of hex characters represents the value of a byte. 128 characters -> 64 bytes* by [jps](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7329832/jps) could be illuminated (and solved) in Python<sup>(1)</sup> in more ways, e.g. as follows:

```
hexstr = '3f5b2e3acfd36066b8cb4114e706d79d270c7c4219a6312c4b40f995f138c2ba5ba2b62aa4831e0bdac8f8802626d3c4f8872b8996d8bebc5ab697e0c702a6eb'
print( len(hexstr))
print( hexstr)

bytes_object = bytes.fromhex(hexstr)

import binascii
print( bytes_object == binascii.unhexlify(hexstr))

import codecs
print( bytes_object == codecs.decode(hexstr, 'hex_codec'))

print( len(bytes_object))
print( bytes_object)
```

**Result**: `.\SO\72880674.py`

```
128
3f5b2e3acfd36066b8cb4114e706d79d270c7c4219a6312c4b40f995f138c2ba5ba2b62aa4831e0bdac8f8802626d3c4f8872b8996d8bebc5ab697e0c702a6eb
True
True
64
b"?[.:\xcf\xd3`f\xb8\xcbA\x14\xe7\x06\xd7\x9d'\x0c|B\x19\xa61,K@\xf9\x95\xf18\xc2\xba[\xa2\xb6*\xa4\x83\x1e\x0b\xda\xc8\xf8\x80&&\xd3\xc4\xf8\x87+\x89\x96\xd8\xbe\xbcZ\xb6\x97\xe0\xc7\x02\xa6\xeb"
```

---

<sup><sup>(1)</sup> I suppose you know *Python basics* since your another questions…</sup>